# SQL - Join query running slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to get data from 3 different tables, like below:

```
SELECT urs.id
    ,urs.username
    ,urs.b_avg_update
    ,urs.b_set_min_avg
    ,urs.b_set_max_avg
    ,urs.b_min_avg
    ,urs.b_max_avg
    ,trs.TIME
    ,trs.user
    ,sum(trs.amount)
    ,trs.type
    ,ur.user_by
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_by
    FROM xeon_users_rented
    ) AS ur
LEFT JOIN users AS urs ON ur.user_by = urs.username
LEFT JOIN transactions AS trs ON urs.id = trs.user
    AND trs.type = 'Recycle'
    AND trs.TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
GROUP BY ur.user_by
```

However, that query is running quite slow:

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 (812 in total, request took 15.0095 sec)
```

When running an `EXPLAIN` on the above query, this is what I get:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1516    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY urs ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14553   Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   PRIMARY trs ref user,type   user    8   littlebu_maindb.urs.id  6   Using where
2   DERIVED xeon_users_rented   range   NULL    idx_user_by 62  NULL    1516    Using index for group-by
```

I have tried to add `INDEXES` on certain columns in hope of speeding things up a bit:

On the table `xeon_users_rented`:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  
xeon_users_rented   0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   37897   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   0   user    1   user    A   37897   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   user_by 1   user_by A   1579    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   since   1   since   A   4210    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   expire  1   expire  A   7579    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   clicks  1   clicks  A   176 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   clicks_last 1   clicks_last A   5413    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   avg 1   avg A   3445    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   click_hour  1   click_hour  A   46  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   click_minute    1   click_minute    A   102 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_click_hour  1   click_hour  A   46  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_click_minute    1   click_minute    A   112 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_id  1   id  A   37897   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_user    1   user    A   37897   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_user_by 1   user_by A   1515    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_expire  1   expire  A   6316    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_since   1   since   A   4210    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_clicks  1   clicks  A   176 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_clicks_last 1   clicks_last A   5413    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xeon_users_rented   1   idx_avg 1   avg A   3445    NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

On the table `users`:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  
users   0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   14554   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
users   1   idx_username    1   username    A   14554   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
users   1   upline  1   upline  A   856 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
users   1   upline  2   upline_expire   A   856 NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

And last but not least, the `transactions` table:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  
transactions    0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   5293    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
transactions    1   user    1   user    A   882 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
transactions    1   type    1   type    A   9   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
transactions    1   amount  1   amount  A   378 NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

I can't see what is causing the slowness. There isn't even 1000 records in total. 
How can I improve my original query and/or database design?

Comment: Are you sure this run? because you only have a field in `GROUP BY  ur.user_by`  and lot of non aggregated field in your select

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes it runs - just really slow.

Comment: I see now. Mysql doesnt validate some `group by` ANSI things. My advice is split your query into small parts, and start adding one by one until you find where you get the slowness.

Comment: Also try remove the `DISTINCT` to measure time, and then try put it on the outside query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza How would it look like when it's outside the query? Where should it be added? Moving it (and not adding it anywhere) speeded it up by about 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way. I think the `users` should be the one on the `LEFT` side of the JOIN. But if that isnt the query you are looking i will try something else.

```
SELECT urs.username
    ,sum(trs.amount)
FROM users AS urs 
LEFT JOIN xeon_users_rented AS ur
       ON urs.username = ur.user_by 
LEFT JOIN transactions AS trs 
       ON urs.id = trs.user
      AND trs.type = 'Recycle'
      AND trs.TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
WHERE ur.user_by IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ur.user_by
```

Comment: I wonder why you have `urs.username - ur.user_by - urs.id - trs.user` You should have same name for user pk like `user_id`

Comment: Carlos Oropeze this only selects "username" and "trs(amount)" field.  not b_set_min_avg etc.

Comment: I know, but those are just static fields or you want do some aggregated function? I assume those are static and removed for simplify the problem wont affect the perfomance.

Comment: What do you mean by "static" field? I would need the information stored in those fields, based on the (unique) username value.

Comment: I mean if you want a field is already on the table just add it. But if you want a calculated field like `AVG(field)` that is different because you need change the `group by`. But we are just trying to improve perfomance. Adding 1 or 10 fields doesnt change much.

Comment: So fo this version provide the same result and improve your performace?

Comment: Query only took .5 seconds!

Comment: `5` seconds or `0.5` ?

Answer (score 0):

Often, these types of queries can run faster using correlated subqueries rather than `group by` at the outer level.  You are pulling arbitrary fields from `transactions`, so let me assume that you only want `amount`.  And that `username` is unique.  Then you can write the query as:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT sum(trs.amount)
        FROM transactions trs
        WHERE u.id = trs.user AND trs.type = 'Recycle' AND
              trs.TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
       ) as amt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_by
      FROM xeon_users_rented
     ) AS xur JOIN
     users u
     ON xur.user_by = u.username;
```

Then, indexes on `users(username)` and `transactions(user, type, time, amount)` are optimal for this query.

Comment: This gives me this error: ¨- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT sum(trs.amount) FROM transactions trs WHERE u.id = trs.u' at line 2¨

Comment: @oliverbj . . . It was a missing comma on the first line.  This method should be faster than the other answer.